# Node.js class with MySQL package using OOP principles

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, oop, npm

I'm learning how to work with MySQL in Node and it's pure pain.

The npm package is 'mysql'.
I'm making an app that follows OOP principles and i was trying to make an independent class that would handle my DB requests. The problem i have is that i can't drop the connection to my database as methods such as `connection.end()` or `connection.drop()` don't work properly even after wrapping them in `.then`

Here's how it looks:

```
    class DB {
    constructor(dbname, dbpassword) {
        this.dbname = dbname;
        this.dbpassword = dbpassword;
    }

    connection() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(mysql.createConnection({
                host: "localhost",
                user: "root",
                password: this.dbpassword,
                database: this.dbname,
            }))
        })
    }

    connect() {
        this.connection().then(res => {
            res.connect(function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(res.state, "connected")
            })
        })
    }

    dropConnection() {
        this.connection().then(res => {
            res.end(); console.log(res.state, 'connection dropped');
        })
    }
}
```

for some reason i cannot drop the connection as i wanted it to. The method `res.end()` doesn't work.
I just want to know if:
a) I'm doing the right thing by trying to fit everything in a single class and calling my actions method by method (i'm trying to follow OOP principles since i might have multiple DBs that will be doing almost similar tasks).
b) There's something wrong with my code that i don't see.

Comment: Every call to `connection()` is creating a new connection.  So you call connect(), and you make a new connection, and do stuff.  You then call `dropConnection()`, which also calls `connection()` and makes a second connection, and then you close the second connection

Comment: My first gut reaction would be that when you create a connection, store it on the class instance.  Repeated calls to `connect` should return the same connection.  When you call dropConnection, close the connection if it exists and null it out.  Otherwise, do nothing

Comment: Thank you @Taplar! How would you store it on the class instance? Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class DB {
  constructor(dbname, dbpassword) {
    this.establishedConnection = null;
    this.dbname = dbname;
    this.dbpassword = dbpassword;
  }

  connection() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: this.dbpassword,
        database: this.dbname,
      }))
    })
  }

  connect() {
    if (!this.establishedConnection) {
      this.establishedConnection = this.connection().then(res => {
        res.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            this.dropConnection();
            throw err;
          }
          
          console.log(res.state, "connected")
        })
      });
    }
  }

  dropConnection() {
    if (this.establishedConnection) {
      this.establishedConnection.then(res => {
        res.end();
        console.log(res.state, 'connection dropped');
      });
      
      this.establishedConnection = null;
    }
  }
}
```

- The `constructor()` has a new class property of `establishedConnection` which will be the promise that returns the connection
- When the `connect()` is called, if there is not an establishedConnection it will make a new one
- If there is a problem with the connection, it will call the `dropConnection()` method
- When the `dropConnection()` method is called, if there is an establishedConnection, it will attempt to perform a close and then null it out

Comment: i now have a question. Is settiing our connection as an accessible property of our class like this against OOP's abstraction or is this particular case fine?

Comment: @qurquru Can you elaborate on your reasoning that making properties accessable on an object is anti-object oriented programming?  If all objects didn't have accessable properties, what would be their point?  Keeping in mind, methods on an object are also "properties".  The name of each of your methods is a property on the class instance.  They just happen to point to functions.